# Java: Compare objects using >, < and ==

Tags: java, object, comparable

Is it possible to properly compare objects using the operators `>`, `<` and `==` in Java?
I have implemented the `Comparable` interface in one of my objects.

It would save some time and be nice to write

```
if (obj1 < obj2) do sth
```

instead of

```
if (obj1.compareTo(obj2) < 0) do sth
```

Is that possible if I implement something else or does it generally not work like this?

Comment: No Java does not support operator overloading (except for Strings that you can concatenate with +).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a word- no, it is not possible.
Java does not support operator overloading, and the comparison operators (`<`, `<=`, `>` and `<=`) are reserved for primitive types only.

Answer (score 5):

No, this is not possible. Java does not support operator overloading.

You might want to check [Groovy](http://beta.groovy-lang.org/), which is a Java like language that runs on the JVM and does support operator overloading.

Comment: @CGFoX You can also check Scala which runs on the JVM and support operator overloading (you could even mix Scala and Java code).

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible. These operators only work on primitive types.

Answer (score 0):

< > Operators are only usable on primitives - such as integers.